# Asymptotic value of a summation

Tags: summation, asymptotics, approximation

Let $q$ be an arbitrary number from $[0, \pi]$. Consider the summation

$$ S (x) = \frac{1}{L} \sum_{i=0}^L \cos \left(2 \frac{q}{L} k x - \theta(\frac{q}{L} k ) \right) ,  $$

where the function $\theta$ is defined as

$$ \theta (y) = 2 \arctan \frac{1 }{2 \sin y } . $$

How can I calculate $S $ to the accuracy of $1/L^2$?

The difficulty comes from the $\theta$ function. But it is a slowly varying function. Therefore, one might somehow use the same trick as used in calculating the summation

$$ \frac{1}{L} \sum_{i=0}^L \cos \left(2 \frac{q}{L} k x \right) .  $$

The result I guessed is

$$ S(x) \simeq \frac{1}{ 2 L \sin \frac{q}{L} x} \left [\sin(2 q x - \theta(q) + \frac{q}{L} x) - \sin (\frac{q}{L} x) \right] . $$

But I am not sure it is accurate on the order of $1/L^2$. How to make it more systematic?

Comment: isn't the term in brackets $O(L^{-3})$ and the prefactor $O(1)$?

Comment: No, the term in the bracket is $O(1)$

Comment: This is a Riemann sum, i.e. $$\lim_{L \to \infty} S(x) = \int_0^1 \cos[2qtx-\theta(qt)]\,dt,$$ so you can probably get somewhere with the Euler-Maclaurin sum formula.